# Extract the scale from tooltip HighStock/HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a HighStock chart. I need to know a scale from the tooltip: the week from some Monday, month or current day. This is a fragment of my event:

```
 plotOptions: {
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (event) {
                            var interval = this.series.pointInterval;
```

This interval is undefined. What am i doing wrong? The full version of code you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/swqubvrf/3/

Thanks.

Comment: In your fiddle ,The this.series.options does not has that pointInterval attribute. check the json here http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b4666e66209ed2d2c4c09fb457a305fe   Could you elaborate a little more what you mean to "interval" ?

Comment: @NishithKantChaturvedi Yes, it is a mistake, but `this.series.pointInterval` is also NULL. Why?

Comment: You don't have `pointInterval` set in options anyway, so that value is undefined. Instead use `this.series.closestPointRange`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/swqubvrf/6/